# How to fix "file /etc/init.d from install of <package> conflicts with file from package chkconfig"

Tags: centos, debian, init.d

I have converted `Debian` package installation to `CentOS` `RPM` using `alian`. I'm getting below error when I try to install it.

Error:

```
file /etc/init.d from install of <package> conflicts with file from package chkconfig
```

I can install it by `rpm -Uvh --force` but I'm getting `Not starting : <package> disabled.` when I try to start it using `init.d`.

I'm not sure how to what is the correct path to track the issue. I appreciate some help.

Comment: Hi do you remember if the solution given was able to solve this problem?

Comment: Can't remember now Caesar.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the conflict you should exclude `/etc/init.d` from the .spec file. e.g.

```
%files
/etc
%exclude %dir /etc/init.d
```

This will only exclude the `/etc/init.d` directory. Any files under `/etc/init.d/*` will still be included.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this but it wasn’t able to solve the problem. Im currently on a VM (SSH-in-browser) and I used vim to access the .spec files. Then I followed your comments and it doesn’t seem to work.